# BMS (battery management system) peak current limit

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am trying to choose a BMS for a 18s6p lipo battery pack i am building.
i am expecting a 180 A discharge current, but most of the options i found had a maximum discharge Current of about 100 A.
my question is why a BMS would have a maximum discharge current limit even though this current doesn't run through the BMS itself ?

Comment: I believe usually a battery management system will have some transistors which are used to control that battery discharge. It might be the physical limitations of said transistors (Note that this is an educated guess and thus a comment)

Comment: The current does run through the BMS, else it wouldn't be able to turn it off in an overcurrent event. Usually some fairly well sized MOSFETs.

Comment: If you claim that discharge current doesn't run through the BMS, I'd like to see a schematic of your connections.

Comment: If you are asking this question, maybe you shouldn't be doing anything with 100-180 A and LiPo batteries. They are quite dangerous if not cared for properly.

Answer (score 3):

As an EE that works on batteries, I agree with RodezIO.  Every BMS system we make contains or communicates with protection mechanisms that the current flows through.  We have a vehicle battery that has a 1100A crank capability, this all flows through a "power board" that has a couple dozen power FETs and is built using a metal substrate instead of FR4.  We also have batteries that can output power on the order of a MW and it all flows through contactors and relays that are controlled by the BMS to cut charge/discharge if a problem occurs.  All these components need to be able to handle the currents, which can be quite a challenge. So yes, the current does run through components that are part of, or controlled by, the BMS.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a BMS is to protect the battery. To avoid battery damage a BMS must be able to stop an overcurrent. In a normal condition **the current flow through the BMS** and when a failure occurs it stops the current.